# Celeryd worker received task but do not work

Tags: python, django, worker, celeryd

My develop env. is

base : python 2.7, Django==1.11, celery==3.1.25

```
VM #01 : nginx + gunicorn (web)
VM #02 : RabbitMQ server on ubuntu 14.04
VM #03 : celery worker
```

*Case #1 : Normal works*

1. RabbitMQ running
2. celeryd worker running
3. and push the async messages to rabbitmq 
   => it works very well,

*Case #2 : Receive the task but do not fire in worker.*

1. RabbitMQ running
2. push the async messages to rabbitmq  ( without running worker )
3. and then execute the celeryd worker

=> it received task but do not work. ..

celeryd logs for case of #2 is

```
[2017-07-13 14:37:21,327: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: task.campaign.update_revenues[faf1b584-9af9-437f-a5e5-ce54749b73e9]
```

that's all. no more logs. no task logs(success?fail?).
and the message  still exist in rabbitmq.

why not executed the tasks ?

Any helps for me ?